# SharePoint field required on task form

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I have a task form (OOB) where user needs to enter comments only when clicks on rejected button.
I wrote following script but this is firing even when clicked on approved button.

```
$('input[value=Rejected]').click(function() {
PreSaveAction();
});
});

function PreSaveAction()
{
var commentsBox = getFieldControl('ApprovalComments','Text');
var comments=$("textarea[title='ApprovalComments']").val(); 
if(comments.length==0)
{
var errorHtml='';
errorHtml = '<span class="ms-formvalidation"><span role="alert">Please enter Comments<br></span>        </span>';

commentsBox.after(errorHtml);
return false;
}
return false;
}
  function getFieldControl(fieldName,fieldType)
{
var control = $('[id^=' + fieldName + '_][id$=' + fieldType + 'Field]');
return control;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can actually achieve it easily. Below is the jquery code sample:

```
function PreSaveAction()
{
    var currentPage = decodeURIComponent(window.location.href.replace(/\+/g, " "));
    if (currentPage.contains("Lists/WorkflowTasks/EditForm.aspx")) 
    {
        var commentsTextArea=$("textarea[title='ApprovalComments']");
        if(commentsTextArea.val().trim()=="")
        {
            var errorHtml='';
            errorHtml = '<span class="ms-formvalidation"><span role="alert">Please enter Comments<br></span></span>';
            commentsTextArea.after(errorHtml);
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

String.prototype.contains = function (it) {
    return this.indexOf(it) != -1;
};
```

***Explanation:***

- **PreSaveAction** method will be triggered in all the New and Edit Forms in SP2010/SP2013.
- Hence there is no need of Button onClick methods for client side validation on these forms.
- In the above code, when you click of Save/Approved/Rejected buttons in your page, PreSaveAction will be fired.
- We will be checking if current page is of Task Forms (**WorkflowTasks** is the name of the task List , please update this accordingly), else ***return true***.
- If the ApprovalComments is empty then error message will be shown and ***return false***.
- Else, ***return true***.
- Also notice the helper method **String.prototype.contains**.